# PWM switching, Regarding the control voltage

Tags: pwm, duty-cycle

[image]

If V desired and V actual is subtracted, in this diagram, how does the V control which should be very same used as reference? My question is that, the V control can be very small, how can it be able to used in the comparator?.
can anyone please tell me what's exactly going on in here!

Comment: Diagram is highly simplified. First stage is depicted as an "amplifier" but is missing all of the passives needed to define gain, and if implemented as depicted will act as a comparator.

Comment: I don't understand your main question though. If the v_control is very small then the gain of the amplifier has been poorly chosen, or the output duty cycle will be correctly low.

Comment: My question is that when the V actual is subtracted from V desired, The signal amplitude must be very low. and you can amplify the signal, to increase the amplitude and compare it with the comparator. But why is this needed, can't we just provide a reference Vo instead. and compare it with a repetitive waveform like sawtooth?

Comment: _The signal amplitude must be very low_ - no. I'm not sure why you're getting that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design the amplifier to whatever gain is needed (this will affect stability).  The control signal should be designed to have a range roughly equal to the peaks of the sawtooth waveform.

I'm guessing you mean the output is small when Vcontrol and Vactual are equal.  However, when you give the amplifier enough gain, it can still cover the PWM range.  There's not really a "zero" control voltage here; it's a matter of what duty cycle results in Vactual being sufficiently close to Vcontrol.  The gain is finite, so there will usually be a remaining error; the goal is to make it as small as possible.

If you assume arbitrarily large gain you can theoretically reduce the error to zero (and learn a few things about stability).

Comment: but my question is since the difference between the V actual and V desired must be low, the V control must be very less. What's the point of getting the difference between V desired and V actual and the amplify it and then give it to the comparator when we can directly given a <voltage reference> to the comparator with the differential amplifier?

Comment: That would allow you to control the duty cycle directly.  The version with feedback allows you to control whatever is providing the feedback voltage (for instance, the feedback voltage might be derived from a power supply output, a motor speed, the brightness of a light, etc.)  If you know the exact duty cycle you need to accomplish your design goal,, you can set it directly as you mention, but the feedback approach inherently compensates for device/component variation, environmental conditions, and other variations that may be unknown a priori.

Comment: Thank you much I got the point